# Proximal Operator image of convex functionals

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, convex-optimization, hilbert-spaces, convex-analysis, regularization

Let $\Gamma_0$ denote the set of lower-semi-continuous convex functionals on a Hilbert space $H$.  What exactly is the image of $\Gamma_0$ under the proximal operator 
$$
\begin{aligned}
&\Gamma_0\rightarrow \{f:H \rightarrow H\}\\
& f \mapsto \left[\operatorname{argmin}_{h \in H} \|x-h\|_H^2 +\frac1{2}f(h) \right].
\end{aligned}
$$
(Not its co-domain, but what characterizes it's image?)

**Necessary:**
*Here are a few necessary conditions I've noted so far.*

- The functions in its image must have a convex domain, since the Moreau envelope is convex, and $Prox_f$ associates the outputs of the Moreau envelope with elements of its domain.

Comment: There should be a square norm in the definition of the proximal map.

Comment: @cheyp Thanks, for pointing that out :)

Comment: I do not believe that your first condition is necessary: If $f$ is the indicator function of $\{0\}$, then the proximal operator is $x \mapsto 0$ and this is not invertible. Second, the domain of a proximal operator is always $H$, i.e., it is trivially convex.

Comment: True, that's a good example.  I'll edit the question.

Comment: The prox equals identity minus the gradient of the Moreau envelope of $f$ (which is a strongly convex function). Does that help?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure that it is going to work but it seems to me that this is the Legendre transform:
$$\|x-h\|^2+\frac{1}{2}f(h)=\|x\|^2-2\Re\langle x,h\rangle+\|h\|^2+\frac{1}{2}f(h) $$ (Where we see $H$ as a $\mathbb{R}$ linear space and $\Re\langle .,.\rangle$ is the real scalar product. So if we call $$h_\min =\text{argmin} (-\Re\langle 2x,h\rangle+\|h\|^2+\frac{1}{2}f(h)) $$
and $$-g(2x)=\min_h (-\Re\langle 2x,h\rangle+\|h\|^2+\frac{1}{2}f(h)) \\= -\Re\langle 2x,h_\min\rangle+\|h_\min\|^2+\frac{1}{2}f(h_\min)$$Then $g$ is the Legendre transform of $h\rightarrow \|h\|^2+\frac{1}{2}f(h)$. And there is the formula $$h_\min =\partial_x g $$
So I thing one should first caracterize the Legendre transform of the set $[\|h\|^2+\frac{1}{2}f(h), f\in \Gamma_0]$ and take its differential.